# message.content.startswith is not a function

Tags: function, discord, prefix, discord.js

**Here is my code:**

```
if (message.content.startswith(prefix+'ping')) {
    message.channel.sendmessage('pong! \'${date.now() -message.createdtimemestamp} ms\'');
} else
```

It gives me an error

TypeError: message.content.startswith is not a function

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Easy. You have misspelt `startsWith()`. Notice that the letter "W" is in capital. In fact, when naming variables in Javascript, compounded words are capitalized except for the first one. This also applies for `sendMessage()`, but do not use it as that's deprecated, use `send()` instead. So you are supposed to do:

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ping')) {
    message.channel.send('Pong!' + `${date.now() -message.createdtimemestamp} ms`);
}
```